# Couchbase created huge GSI index files

Tags: couchbase

We faced an issue with Couchbase, where it generated 150Gb [secondary index](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/indexes/gsi-for-n1ql.html) file for a bucket which has only 26.4GB data.

We got an error in the night:

```
2018-09-13T22:47:18.552Z+05:30 [Error] IndexerSettingsManager: metakv notifier failed (unexpected EOF)..Restarting
2018/09/13 22:47:18 revrpc: Got error (EOF) and will retry in 1s

panic: 2018-09-13T22:47:24.896Z+05:30 [Error] IndexerSettingsManager: metakv notifier failed (Get http://127.0.0.1:8091/_metakv/?feed=continuous: CBAuth database is stale: last reason: EOF)..Restarting
CBAuth database is stale: last reason: EOF
```

After that indexer was only publishing these logs:

```
2018-09-14T03:53:45.284Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8340 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.314Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8370 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.344Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8400 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.374Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8430 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.404Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8460 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.434Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8490 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.464Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8520 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.494Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8550 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.524Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8580 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.554Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8610 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.584Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8640 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.614Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8670 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.644Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8700 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.674Z+05:30 [Warn] Indexer::MutationQueue Waiting for Node Alloc for 8730 Milliseconds Vbucket 984
2018-09-14T03:53:45.7Z+05:30 [Info] logWriterStat:: 5308082947943612037 FlushedCount 33730000 QueuedCount 7840
```

However it was I guess writing index file also in background and it created following files, which cause 100% disk full.

```
sudo ls -lrth /storage/1/couchbase/index/@2i/myBucket_idx_5308082947943612037_0.index
total 181G
-rw-rw---- 1 couchbase couchbase  31G Sep 14 03:53 data.fdb.418
-rw-rw---- 1 couchbase couchbase 150G Sep 14 03:59 data.fdb.417
```

Couchbase version Community: 4.0.0-4051-1

Please let us know, how to debug it further, what can be cause of this?

I see few issues related to this, but not much help from them: [MB-19145](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-19145), [MB-20464](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-20464), [MB-18912](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-18912), [MB-14962](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-14962), [MB-25086](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-25086)

Edit:

index on this table:

```
        "indexes": {
            "datastore_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
            "id": "40d3a82d781dad05",
            "index_key": [],
            "is_primary": true,
            "keyspace_id": "myTable",
            "name": "#primary",
            "namespace_id": "default",
            "state": "online",
            "using": "gsi"
        },
        {
        "indexes": {
            "datastore_id": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
            "id": "b870f85dc1cadd5",
            "index_key": [
                "(meta().`id`)"
            ],
            "keyspace_id": "myTable",
            "name": "idx",
            "namespace_id": "default",
            "state": "online",
            "using": "gsi"
        }
```

Comment: Could you please list the indexes that you made? Any particular reason you're using 4.0 instead of 5.0 or even 4.5.1?

Comment: @MatthewGroves added index info in the question. Its difficult to update at this point, as this is used by a legacy system.

Comment: There only one index, and it's a primary index? For 26gb of data, that seems like a really bad idea that will lead to some very slow N1QL queries. The primary index really isn't meant for most production scenarios. What kind of queries are you running?

Comment: @MatthewGroves Sorry there were two indexes.

Comment: The other index is on `meta().id` which seems redundant. Neither one of these indexes seem like they would be a good choice for a 26gb database in production. I'm speculating, but this may be the reason that your disk space usage has blown up